# Simplest method for passing flag between two separate .net processes

Tags: vb.net, ipc

I have two separate vb.net applications.  One is a GUI frontend WinForm and the other is a console application which handles file transfers and runs in the background.  The file transfer application monitors a directory and when new files are found, it transfers the files to a destination.  It checks that the remote destination is accessible.  I would like to have a flag which indicates the file transfer task can connect to remote destination and display this status on the GUI.

Example of how the GUI application starts the File Transfer console application:

```
Public FileXferProcess As Process
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("FileXfer.exe")
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
FileXferProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
```

I know there are many different types of interprocess communication techniques but I am looking for the simplest solution for sharing a boolean state.

Comment: Please provide more context. Does the GUI application start the file transfer process itself? Or does it have to hook into an already running task?

Comment: Is the "other" VB.NET application a Windows Service?

Comment: @paulroho Starting the file transfer process from the GUI application with 'Process.Start'.

Comment: @AndrewMorton console application which runs without window

Comment: You have not provided much context, but perhaps you could poll the [Process.HasExited Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited.aspx) with a timer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have added more context in the description.  I wasn't sure how much detail to go into without complicating the original question at hand

Comment: Well, in the time it's taken to get to here, you might as well have implemented using a file to flag the status, or a memory pipe, or a system-wide mutex. As you're asking, then the file method might be the simplest. Just be sure to take into consideration that the power could be lost from the computer at the most inconvenient time possible and write your code appropriately.

Comment: Since you are starting a console application, does it produce any output that you can use to monitor the transfer status?  If so, maybe you can you redirect the output (`startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True`) and handle the `FileXferProcess.OutputDataReceived` event to capture the output?

Comment: The file approach leaves a lot to consider for handling if the program is still really active and file locked in-use etc; the mutex approach I have considered but do not really understand the implementation with handling the check if exists without inadvertently obtaining ownership. And anyways thought that was not the true purpose for mutexes.  The named pipe approach may be the best choice.  Could you provide a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a mutex to pass a flag between the separate processes.  That does not require any overhead and handles if the process if abruptly closed (since the mutex will be destroyed with the task that created it).

Below are code snippets:

*In File Transfer task*

```
Public hMutex_Connected As Mutex
...

' If connected, set mutex
hMutex_Connected = New Mutex(True, "FileXfer_Connected")
...

' If disconnected, destroy mutex
hMutex_Connected.Close()
```

*In Main application GUI*

```
Public Function IsConnected() As Boolean
  Dim bConnected As Boolean = False
  Try
     Mutex.OpenExisting("FileXfer_Connected")
     bConnected = True
  Catch ex As WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException
     ' "Mutex does not exist."
  Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
     ' "Unauthorized access: " & ex.Message
  Catch ex As Exception
     ' ex.ToString
  End Try

  Return bConnected
End Function
```